# switched to laravel 5.5, my resource loading is stalled

Tags: laravel, server, resources, php-7

I have no problems loading in multiple resources in my previous laravel applications 5.2.*. I just started a new app in laravel 5.5.* and i'm noticing that when loading in css and js files, these are stalled in the browser. This makes pageloads superslow. I'm running php artisan serve as usual.

Does anyone have an idea why this is happening?

```
{
"name": "laravel/laravel",
"description": "The Laravel Framework.",
"keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
"license": "MIT",
"type": "project",
"require": {
    "php": ">=7.0.0",
    "appstract/laravel-bootstrap-components": "^0.2.0",
    "fideloper/proxy": "~3.3",
    "hesto/multi-auth": "^2.0",
    "laravel/framework": "5.5.*",
    "laravel/tinker": "~1.0",
    "yajra/laravel-datatables": "^1.0"
},
"require-dev": {
    "filp/whoops": "~2.0",
    "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
    "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "~6.0"
},
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "database/seeds",
        "database/factories"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/"
    }
},
"autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Tests\\": "tests/"
    }
},
"extra": {
    "laravel": {
        "dont-discover": [
        ]
    }
},
"scripts": {
    "post-root-package-install": [
        "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
    ],
    "post-create-project-cmd": [
        "@php artisan key:generate"
    ],
    "post-autoload-dump": [
        "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
        "@php artisan package:discover"
    ]
},
"config": {
    "preferred-install": "dist",
    "sort-packages": true,
    "optimize-autoloader": true
}
```

}

[image]

[image]

Comment: let's just concat and minify all css files and it'll load faster, but still...